# MATLAB concatenate 2D matrix tiles

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I have n<sup>2</sup> equally sized (8x8) matrices which I want to tile into a single matrix like in the following diagram: 
[image: diagram]

I know I could concatenate them column by column and then concatenate each row, but I want to know if there's a simpler method to achieve this.

Comment: How are the `n^2` matrices stored? As separate variables with some sort of naming scheme? In a cell array? In an N-D array (3+ dimensional array)?

Comment: Currently I'm forming them inside a for loop in which I was also trying to append them to the large matrix so they're not explicitly stored.

Comment: just `A=[A1,A2;A3,A4]` will do... (with A1-A4 your sub matrices)

Comment: The number of sub matrices isn't limited to 4, any arbitrary square number.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I didn't read too carefully. What do you mean by " forming them inside a for loop " ? what exactly do you do?

Comment: I have a row vector of values from which I select the values up to the next end-of-sequence flag, pad the values (with zeros) to length 64 then reshape to 8x8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simpler method, you can store all your matrices in a cell array, then reshape and convert back to a matrix:

In the following example, suppose that `C` is your n<sup>2</sup>×1 cell array of matrices:

```
cell2mat(reshape(C, sqrt(numel(C)), []));
```

The result is a single tiled matrix `A` as required.

#### Example

```
a = ones(2); b = 2 * a; c = 3 * a; d = 4 * a;
C = {a, b, c, d};
A = cell2mat(reshape(C, sqrt(numel(C)), []))
```

The result is:

```
A =
     1     1     3     3
     1     1     3     3
     2     2     4     4
     2     2     4     4
```

Note the order of the sub-matrices: they are arranged column-wise. If you want `A` to be:

```
A =
     1     1     2     2
     1     1     2     2
     3     3     4     4
     3     3     4     4
```

then you'll have to pass the transposed version of `C` to reshape:

```
cell2mat(reshape(C', sqrt(numel(C)), []))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a `for` loop where you create the 8-by-8 matrices, you can do something like this:

```
M = 8; % Rows of each block matrix
N = 8; % Columns of each square block matrix
m = 2; % Number of blocks across
n = 2; % Number of blocks vertically
A(m*n*M,N) = 0; % Preallocate an m*n*M-by-N column of blocks
for i = 1:m*n
    a = rand(M,N);          % Create your data, just random here
    A(1+M*(i-1):M*i,:) = a; % Insert data
end
A = reshape(A,[M*m N*n]); % Reshape to obtain block matrix
```

This assumes that you have a single `for` loop iterating over all `n^2` (or `m*n`) cases. Also, it builds up `A` one column of blocks at a time. Note: if you need to build it with the blocks going across the rows first, then you'll need to change the allocation of `A` and how the data is inserted by swapping the indices.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is!

```
%Assuming your matrices are A1, A2, A3 and A4:
A = zeros(size(A1)*2);
A(1:8,1:8) = A1;
A(9:16, 1:8) = A2;
A(1:8, 9:16) = A3;
A(9:16, 9:16) = A4;
```